# Error: cannot import name 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'

Tags: python, flask, pydantic, testdriven.io

I'm working through the new version (v1.6.0) of the course and am running into an issue when attempting to import 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'.  I'm using v2.6.3 of pydantic and receiving the following error when attempting to bring up the web server:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'`

Answer (score 0):

From the document I can see:

**https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#dataclass-validators**

`field_validator` is present in all the versions `>=2  (2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6)`

```
from pydantic import field_validator
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
```

However, it is not present in version `1.10`